# "Have you seen the movie" vs "Have you ever seen the movie"

Tags: meaning

Consider these

> **Have you seen** the movie Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone?
>
> **Have you ever seen** the movie Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone?

Do they mean the same thing? A native speaker told me the latter is more natural. Why?

Comment: IMO the latter is only more natural among those who watch the same movie over and over again.

Answer (score 3):

Both forms are possible, and they mostly overlap in meaning.
 However the question "Have you ever X" is more likely when X is something that one might do repeatedly. For example, "Have you ever eaten salmon?". One may have eaten it many times, or not at all. The question asks whether you have done it at least once.

"Have you seen the movie X" probably refers to something that you would only have done once, if at all.

Examples:
**Have you ever** fallen in love?
**Have you ever** driven a car?

**Have you** finished your degree?
**Have you** gotten your driver's license?

Going back to your particular example,

**Have you seen** the movie 'Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone'?
**Have you ever seen** a Harry Potter movie?

Comment: A fuller version of my comment!

Comment: @Weather Vane. Really? I thought you were saying the *opposite*!

Comment: You made it clear in the second sentence of your answer. It is the same as what I wrote.

Comment: @WeatherVane  I agreed with your comment. "Ever" is more natural for possibly repeated stuff, not for one-time things.

Comment: Also, "Have you seen...?" could be used of a recent film, with an implied "yet".

Comment: So, "Have you seen the movie 'PARASITE' yet?" is more natural, right?